# Python Optimization - Unable to meet multiple constrains

Tags: python, math, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to minimize the weight as close to average as possible and meet both constrain of w>0 and Aw=b. However, with help, I was able to meet the second constrain (Aw=b) almost 100% but my w still return negative and at the same time not as close to average. As you can see the result below returns two large negative number (-39.99771255,-2.9709434) and one large position number (43.82670431) that are out of bound, which defeat the purpose of the exercise to minimize the weight.  I even tried to divide my data set to randomly different groups as well but no optimized solution.

Please let me know if there are any math or better python suggestions as well as any methodology that could help lead to the most optimized solution. I am expecting the number to be as close as 0.2. Any numerical suggestion and advise are very welcome.

> Question: Find the minimized weight that are close to average and at
>   the same time meet the target as close as possible and weight must be larger 
>   than 0

My math right now is

```
           **min⁡(w-mean(w))**

           **s.t.** Aw-b=0, w>=0


           **bound** 0.2'<'w<0.5
```

---

Data:

```
    variable1   variable2   variable3   weight
    1.49E+03    9.65E+07    2.27E+08    w1
    1.52E+03    1.02E+08    2.20E+08    w2
    1.54E+03    1.11E+08    2.23E+08    w3
    1.49E+03    9.73E+07    2.18E+08    w4
    1.60E+03    1.05E+08    2.38E+08    w5
    1.57E+03    1.01E+08    2.25E+08    w6
    1.59E+03    1.06E+08    2.30E+08    w7
    1.49E+03    9.15E+07    2.20E+08    w8
    1.54E+03    1.02E+08    2.20E+08    w9
    1.54E+03    1.01E+08    2.28E+08    w10
    1.57E+03    1.08E+08    2.25E+08    w11
    1.54E+03    1.00E+08    2.25E+08    w12
    1.57E+03    9.97E+07    2.26E+08    w13
    1.49E+03    9.64E+07    2.13E+08    w14
    1.53E+03    1.05E+08    2.36E+08    w15
    1.53E+03    1.09E+08    2.23E+08    w16
    1.55E+03    1.00E+08    2.45E+08    w17
    1.52E+03    1.07E+08    2.17E+08    w18
    1.50E+03    9.62E+07    2.07E+08    w19
    1.57E+03    9.91E+07    2.32E+08    w20


  Target            
    8531        429386951   1079115532
```

Current Result:

```
('x: ', array([  0.28601612,   0.28601614,  43.82670431,   0.28601614,   0.28601613,   0.28601614,   0.28601614,  -2.9709434 ,
     0.28601614,   0.28601613,   0.28601615,   0.28601613,   0.28601613,   0.28601614,   0.28601614,   0.28601618,
   -39.99771255,   0.28601618,   0.28601614,   0.28601612]))
```

---

Python Code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Nov 9 13:15:49 2017

@author: zkmkq7a
"""

import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as spo
#from __future__ import print_function
import csv
import os
import sys
import operator
import itertools
import random
import numpy as np
from array import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import nnls, minimize
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import networkx as nx
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=120)
np.random.seed(1)

""" Test Solver with random data """
#M, N = 2, 3
#A = np.random.random(size=(M,N))
#x_hidden = np.random.random(size=N)
#b = A.dot(x_hidden)  # target
#n = N
#
#print('Original A')
#print(A)
#print('hidden x: ', x_hidden)
#print('target: ', b)

A = np.array(
[
[1486,1522,1536,1485,1598,1570,1593,1491,1540,1544,1566,1544,1573,1490,1530,1526,1546,1518,1498,1567],
[96454395,101615856,110933285,97323661,104973593,101499747,106069432,91496414,101843454,101040852,107795438,100260356,99722283,96419402,104875509,108908675,100158114,107298576,96209051,99065264],
[226553304,219597259,223410668,217613414,237752337,225150384,230103384,219982453,219726185,227791091,225452565,225279979,225682678,213304290,236148563,223027694,244961198,216856884,207345788,231758040]
]
)

b = np.array([8531., 1079115532., 429386951.])
n = 20

""" Optimize as LP """
def solve(A, b, n):
    print('Reformulation')
    am, an = A.shape

    # Introduce aux-vars
    # 1: y = mean
    # n: z = x - mean
    # n: abs(z)
    n_plus_aux_vars = 3*n + 1

    # Equality constraint: y = mean
    eq_mean_A = np.zeros(n_plus_aux_vars)
    eq_mean_A[:n] = 1. / n
    eq_mean_A[n] = -1.
    eq_mean_b = np.array([0])

    print('y = mean A:')
    print(eq_mean_A)
    print('y = mean b:')
    print(eq_mean_b)

    # Equality constraints: Ax = b
    eq_A = np.zeros((am, n_plus_aux_vars))
    eq_A[:, :n] = A[:, :n]
    eq_b = np.copy(b)

    print('Ax=b A:')
    print(eq_A)
    print('Ax=b b:')
    print(eq_b)

    # Equality constraints: z = x - mean
    eq_mean_A_z = np.hstack([-np.eye(n), np.ones((n, 1)), + np.eye(n), np.zeros((n, n))])
    eq_mean_b_z = np.zeros(n)

    print('z = x - mean A:')
    print(eq_mean_A_z)
    print('z = x - mean b:')
    print(eq_mean_b_z)

    # Inequality constraints: absolute values -> x <= x' ; -x <= x'

    ineq_abs_0_A = np.hstack([np.zeros((n, n)), np.zeros((n, 1)), np.eye(n), -np.eye(n)])
    ineq_abs_0_b = np.zeros(n)

    ineq_abs_1_A = np.hstack([np.zeros((n, n)), np.zeros((n, 1)), -np.eye(n), -np.eye(n)])
    ineq_abs_1_b = np.zeros(n)

    # Bounds
    # REMARK: Do not touch anything besides the first bounds-row!
    bounds = [(-50., 50.) for i in range(n)] +     \
             [(None, None)] +                   \
             [(None, None) for i in range(n)] + \
             [(0, None) for i in range(n)]

    # Objective
    c = np.zeros(n_plus_aux_vars)
    c[-n:] = 1

    A_eq = np.vstack((eq_mean_A, eq_A, eq_mean_A_z))
    b_eq = np.hstack([eq_mean_b, eq_b, eq_mean_b_z])

    A_ineq = np.vstack((ineq_abs_0_A, ineq_abs_1_A))
    b_ineq = np.hstack([ineq_abs_0_b, ineq_abs_1_b])

    print('solve...')
    result = spo.linprog(c, A_ineq, b_ineq, A_eq, b_eq, bounds=bounds, method='interior-point')
    print(result)
    x = result.x[:n]
    print('x: ', x)
    print('residual Ax-b: ', A.dot(x) - b)
    print('residual Ax-b %: ', np.divide(A.dot(x)-b,b))   
    print('mean: ', result.x[n])
    print('x - mean: ', x - result.x[n])
    print('l1-norm(x - mean) / objective: ', np.linalg.norm(x - result.x[n], 1))


solve(A, b, n)
```

Comment: Sorry typo. x is w

Comment: ok. In the code w is x. How should I set up the bounds on the parameters? can you advise?

Comment: The code is not reproducible as the dimensions of A,b and make no sense. Apart from that: you can just select the bounds in ```[(-50., 50.) for i in range(n)]```. But for some values there is no feasible solution given some bounds, independent on how you solve it, with this model. Furthermore the magnitudes of this data is scary. Scaling should be done (centering somehow around 0).

Comment: You complain about values like -40, and +40; yet use bounds -50, +50. ??? Do you understand what you are doing (that's more important than scaling right now)? Depending on A and b, there is no solution with values in (-1,1) only. At least for this model.

Comment: well, when I set my bound to 0.2-0.4. The results become ('x: ', array([ 1.34787781,  0.8928625 ,  1.04631747,  1.11338831,  1.26451207,  0.95370605,  0.90989891,  1.17944311,
        0.8236745 ,  1.19021942,  0.81689471,  1.11028755,  1.0350795 ,  0.93481318,  1.45152743,  0.91133625,
        0.10596648,  0.99331033,  0.66931618,  1.27057417])) Residual becomes over array([  33.1389416%,   125.888295%,  1154.222562%]))

Comment: This all makes not much sense. (1) Understand your model. There are *equality-constraints* *potentially* effecting results in a non-adjustable way! Think about a row in A with only one nonzero-value! (2) The *equality-constraint* Ax-b = 0 effects in either feasible and Ax-b=0 / near zero-norm error or infeasible! This means: your ```residual Ax-b %``` does not make sense. Even worse: don't trust the optimizer result, without reading out the status (x might be returned even in the infeasible case)!

Comment: Ok Just to make sure I understand instead of using residual % to measure my error rate, which does not accurately capture the my errors. In addition, I should set up my equality constrain Ax-b to something else? We tried the following model. But the residual error become over 13%, which is why we use the approach above. min⁡〖ΣN_i (w_i-w ̅ )^2 〗
s.t.
∑w_i L_i=Var1_target
∑w_i N_i=Var2_target
∑w_i U_i=Var_target
Where w ̅=(∑N_i w_i)/(SumN_i )

Comment: What should i say? You want to minimize the residual and the similarity of weights. These are conflicting objectives in general and nothing you observed is surprising in theory. The approach above is a (hard-)constrained one, where Ax-b is always ~ 0 and the similarity is minimized. This leads to cases where there is no solution. If using a two objectives, where the norm(Ax-b) is part of the objective, no equality-constraint anymore, one need to give scalars to weight those conflicting objectives. It's easier to see the effects too. But it's not a linear-program anymore.

Comment: Using cvxpy, you could play around with all these approaches (as long as convex) with a few lines of code (actually only the mean needs special care). But this only helps if the basic theory is clear.

Comment: You are right. Sorry if I have cause any confusions. The objective of minimizing the variance of the weight is to keep the weighted sample as closely distributed as the sampling pool as possible. I used the 'SLSQP' method before. Would that still be the best solver for multi-objective optimization?

Comment: There is no best solver. And multi-objective optimization is a more broad topic. If you a-priori decided on the obj_a + x * obj_b approach, and your approach is convex (usually yes), cvxpy is by far the best modelling-tool and the solvers brought (Convex-optimization solvers) will be better than SLSQP (which is more general).

Comment: Ok Make sense. I will try cvxpy. I am having a little hard time setting up my objectives in convex optimization solver. I was using least square which is min⁡〖ΣN_i (w_i-w ̅ )^2 〗given the constrain what do you think it's the best way to set up the objectives?

Comment: There is no best way. But i would start with something like ```norm(w-wmean) + c * norm(Ax-b)```. (in cvxpy-terms this is the l2-norm; l1 would look like ```norm(x, 1)```)

Comment: Note that your "math" model is not correct. That looks like an unbounded problem.